# Get random number on command line on MacOs (like shuf)

Tags: macos

I need add random number to filename. On Linux I use command like

```
filename$(shuf -i 10000000-99999999 -n 1)
```

But on MacOs  with this command I recieve error:

```
sh: shuf: command not found
```

Here are another solution on MacOs for make it?

Comment: Thank you so much guys! 
I'll try to use the **tgallacher's** solution with caution, watching if there will be errors due to too fast file generation. I like the ability to sort files by the time they are generated.
If the solution does not work good, I will use simple **Mark Setchell's** solution with RANDOM. I check this answer as solution because it precisely does not lead to errors and is more suitable for the wording of the question.

Comment: Using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/): `sudo port install coreutils` and then `shuf` is available as `gshuf`: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/195380/37190

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
dd bs=4 count=1 if=/dev/urandom 2>/dev/null | xxd -p 
7bfe4143
```

Or with `od`:

```
head -c 4 /dev/urandom | od -An -tu4
2465874330
```

Or with `bash`'s `$RANDOM`:

```
echo $RANDOM$RANDOM
820227815
```

Comment: Yes I use $RANDOM$RANDOM is very simple solution.

Comment: Checked. Thank You =)

Answer (score 17):

Bash $RANDOM is a pretty good solution. Alternatively, you can use "jot", which comes pre-installed on Mac:

```
$ jot -r 1 10000000 99999999
```

if you want to generate more than one number, just change the first parameter

```
$ jot -r 36 10000000 99999999 // Generates 36 Unique Numbers
```

Answer (score 12):

> Install coreutils with `brew install coreutils`

use `gshuf`

Comment: How do you actually use it? I'm in the folder in the mac terminal where I want to shuffle the files. I just typed in gshuf. I'm not sure if its doing anything :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add supplemental tools via HomeBrew, MacOS comes with Ruby and Python builtin.  You can do something like:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e 'p rand(1...10000000)'
```

If you want leading zeros:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e 'printf "%07d\n", rand(1...10000000)'
```

You can append the result to a filename prefix by removing the `\n` and concatenating.  Here's an example:

```
fname=foo`/usr/bin/ruby -e 'printf "%07d", rand(1...10000000)'`; echo $fname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
head -c 8 /dev/urandom | od -An -tu8 |awk '{$1=$1};1'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

A simple approach could to use the current unix timestamp:

```
filename$(date '+%s')
```

Comment: This is not what I call random.

Comment: If the script is creating a batch of thousands files in 10 seconds, I can clearly see a problem here.

Comment: I agree with one of the opponents of the answer that if the files are generated too quickly, this method will be a bad decision, since it will produce the same sequence of numbers. But this method suits me because actually I need generate unique filemane (not necessary use only random numbers for this). In addition to a unique sequence of numbers, this method allows you to sort files by the time they are generated.

Comment: Slight improvement - include nanoseconds: `date '+%s.%N'`